# How to use QApplication::platformNativeInterface() on Linux in Qt 6?

Tags: linux, qt6

How to use `QApplication::platformNativeInterface()` on Linux in Qt 6?

What should I convert returned pointer to on X11 platform? What and how header file should I include into my code? What possible package I should find with CMake to be able to include this functionality?

Simple line of code:

```cpp
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    auto display = QApplication::platformNativeInterface()->display();
```

Leads to compile error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QPlatformNativeInterface’
```